# Can't enter username into popup authentification window Java, selenium (in Safari and Opera)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

Can't enter username into popup authentication window Java, selenium (in Safari and Opera)

This constriction doesn't work both in Safari and Opera:

```
driver.get(“https://username:password@example.com”)
```

And this doesn't work too:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendKeys("Test"); //that is how I am trying to enter login
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you share an error logs?

Comment: I have a message in logs 
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
And test continues to run. Browser window stays opened with authentication popup in it.

Comment: @Yuliia have you given any sleeps before switching to Alert? Please share full code.

Comment: Just try to remove `sleep(5000)` and run the code. And use `Thread.sleep(5000)`

Comment: This is my code. I've tried both with and without sleep:

`public class BasePage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public  BasePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void visit() {
        driver.get(baseURL + projectTest);
        sleep(5000);
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.sendKeys("Test");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

 

 `

Comment: @JitendraBanshpal I've tried both with and without sleep.

my sleep is a separate method
`
public static void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }`

Sorry, there were no space to include it all in one message.

Comment: @Yuliia, try this `public class BasePage { 
 private WebDriver driver;
 public BasePage(WebDriver driver){ 
  this.driver = driver;
 }
 public void visit() throws Exception { 
  driver.get(baseURL + projectTest);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  Thread.sleep(5000); 
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
  alert.sendKeys("Test");
 }
}`

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the pop-up is not an alert at all?  Alerts usually do not prompt for input other than accept or dismiss, and the alert type has those specific methods.  If it's asking for login credentials, it's likely part of the page's DOM.  Use tools to check the web elements for locators and treat it like the rest of the document.

Comment: The pop-up belong to OS = not reachable by selenium. Try driver.get("https://username:password@example.com") instead of driver.get(“https://username:password@example.com”).  But I still doubt it will work in all browsers. Better to use existing browser profile with saved credentials (if possible).

Comment: Hi @pburgr thank you for your reply! Could you please repeat the variant instead of driver.get(“username:password@example.com”). I think there is a typo because 2 constructions are the same.

Comment: “xy” vs "xy" different quation marks. In code use " instead of “ / ”